# How to get list of operating systems URL of Century link cloud API

Tags: java

I have created server on Century link cloud from a `Java` application created internally.

I need to get OS list dynamically from Century link cloud in order to create a server from our `Java` application.

Can anyone please let me know what is the API endpoint for retrieving a list of servers?. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Following is the link that is working for list of data centers:

```
 private static final String GET_URL='https://api.cti.io/V2/datacenters/Alias/';
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question.  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, in the [Create Server](https://www.ctl.io/api-docs/v2/#servers-create-server) you have to set in the Request the **sourceServerId** info or the **osType**.

If you want to create a new server by bare metal servers, you have to specify the osType:

> Only required for bare metal servers. Specifies the OS to provision
>   with the bare metal server. Currently, the only supported OS types are
>   **redHat6_64Bit**, **centOS6_64Bit**,  **windows2012R2Standard_64Bit**, 
>   **windows2012R2Datacenter_64Bit**, **ubuntu14_64Bit**. A list of importable OS
>   types for a given data center can be retrieved from the Get Data
>   Center Bare Metal Capabilities API operation. (Ignored for standard
>   and hyperscale servers.)

Else you can create a server using the **sourceServerId**:

> ID of the server to use a source. May be the ID of a template, or when
>   cloning, an existing server ID. The list of available templates for a
>   given account in a data center can be retrieved from the Get Data
>   [Center Deployment Capabilities API](https://www.ctl.io/api-docs/v2/#data-centers-get-data-center-deployment-capabilities) operation. (Ignored for bare metal
>   servers.)

So you need to do a GET to Center Deployment Capabilities API:

> Gets the list of capabilities that a specific data center supports for
>   a given account, including the deployable networks, OS templates, and
>   whether features like shared load balancer configuration are
>   available.

For example:

```
GET https://api.ctl.io/v2/datacenters/ALIAS/UC1/deploymentCapabilities
```

The response will have something like this:

```
"supportsBareMetalServers":false,
  "supportsSharedLoadBalancer":true,
  "deployableNetworks":[
    {
      "name":"My Network",
      "networkId":"a933432bd8894e84b6c4fb123e48cb8b",
      "type":"private",
      "accountID":"ACCT"
    }
  ],
  "templates":[
    {
      "name":"UBUNTU-14-64-TEMPLATE",
      "description":"Ubuntu 14 | 64-bit",
      "storageSizeGB":17,
      "capabilities":[
        "cpuAutoscale"
      ],
      "reservedDrivePaths":[
        "bin",
        "boot",
        "build",
        "cdrom",
        "compat",
        "dist",
        "dev",
        "entropy",
        "etc",
        "home",
        "initrd.img",
        "lib",
        "lib64",
        "libexec",
        "lost+found",
        "media",
        "mnt",
        "opt",
        "proc",
        "root",
        "sbin",
        "selinux",
        "srv",
        "sys",
        "tmp",
        "usr",
        "var",
        "vmlinuz"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name":"WIN2012R2DTC-64",
      "description":"Windows 2012 R2 Datacenter Edition | 64-bit",
      "storageSizeGB":60,
      "capabilities":[
        "cpuAutoscale"
      ],
      "reservedDrivePaths":[
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d"
      ],
      "drivePathLength":1
    },
    {
      "name":"WA1ACCTCUST01",
      "description":"My Custom Template",
      "storageSizeGB":16,
      "capabilities":[
        "cpuAutoscale"
      ],
      "reservedDrivePaths":[
        "bin",
        "boot",
        "build",
        "cdrom",
        "compat",
        "dist",
        "dev",
        "entropy",
        "etc",
        "home",
        "initrd.img",
        "lib",
        "lib64",
        "libexec",
        "lost+found",
        "media",
        "mnt",
        "opt",
        "proc",
        "root",
        "sbin",
        "selinux",
        "srv",
        "sys",
        "tmp",
        "usr",
        "var",
        "vmlinuz"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

where there are the interested infos.

Note: if you want to know all the Data Center, you can call the [Get Data Center](https://www.ctl.io/api-docs/v2/#data-centers-get-data-center)

If you want to know the lists of all created servers, from [Get Servers By Datacenter](https://www.ctl.io/api-docs/v2/#simple-backup-get-servers-by-datacenter)

> Get a list of servers based on CLC Data Center.

For example

```
GET https://api.backup.ctl.io/clc-backup-api/api/datacenters/VA1%20-%20US%20East%20(Sterling)/servers
```